# Windows Web Server 2008 R2 Server Core local password complexity

Tags: windows, windows-server-core

How can I disable the local user account password complexity settings on Windows 2008 R2 "Server Core"?

I am trying to migrate our windows 2003 web server to windows 2008 R2.  I am trying to see if I can use the "Server Core" install, and it has been a very internet search intensive experience.

What I can't find out how to do is to find out how to disable password complexity for local user accounts.  While our user account generator currently creates nice strong passwords, there was a time when this was not the case and unfortunately forcing the users to change their password is not an option at this time.

Any help greatly appreciated.
*Dennis*

Answer (score 7):

From http://thebackroomtech.com/2008/03/10/windows-server-2008-password-complexity-requirements/

> To lift the password complexity:
>
> secedit /export /cfg C:\new.cfg
>
> Then you edit new.cfg (it is ini
>   format) and change line
>   “PasswordComplexity = 1″ to
>   “PasswordComplexity = 0″.
>
> Apply it with:
>
> secedit /configure /db
>   %windir%\security\new.sdb /cfg
>   C:\new.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY

Comment: Don't forget to also check the "MinimumPasswordLength" line. I disabled the password complexity requirement using the above steps, but didn't realize for a while that I need to change the minimum password length requirement because my password was also shorter than the minimum length.